# How to add a program that can be run from CMD line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using Bash in a linux system, and right now I can do stuff like: "gedit 1.txt" in my terminal.

I want to do it with Sublime text 2, instead of going to my Sublime directory and manually open the program first.

Thanks

Comment: I don't use sublime, but what happens if you just type `sublime somefile`? If that isn't working, either the [tag:sublime] install location isn't in your path or the executable isn't called sublime. In either case figure out where it's installed and add an alias `alias sublime=/some/location/sublime_executable` or if it's the same path, the path to your `$PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

what's problem with you it works for `sublime` also. Also which system you use?

Your PATH might be not contain path to `sublime` executable.So first you can locate it by

```
$ locate sublime
```

And add path of this executable to your `$PATH`

Or if not want to search and add process then please remove sublime from your system and install as follows so it will added to your default path

Remove steps:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2
sudo rm /usr/bin/sublime
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop
sudo sed -i 's/sublime\.desktop/gedit.desktop/g' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Installation steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

After installing go to terminal and type name starting with `sub` or press TAB then it will automiticaly give hint for sub line like

```
sysadmin:~/Desktop$ subl   //after entering some first char then Pressed enter
subl          sublime-text
```

and you will be now able to open sublime via terminal as follows

```
sysadmin:~/Desktop$ sublime-text file1.txt
```